# what ref:'users' do in this line ? : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID , ref:'users')

Tags: mongoose

when should I use object id ? instead of using just String

```
 car:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,ref:'cars'}
 user:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,ref:'users'},
```

instead of just using

```
 type:String
```

?
untill now it was always

```
type:string
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You are defining a relation between specific collections.
   Basically be defining `user:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,ref:'users'},` in a schema, you are telling mongoose, that the `user` attribute is not just a plain string, but a reference to the _id of a document in `users` collection.
   You can then (e.g.) use functions like `.populate('user')` to perform a lookup on this previously defined relation.
2. You are restricting what can be stored in this attribute. If you define this attribute as a plain string, you can store everything you want in it without an error being raised, even if it is no valid _id of a foreign document. Defining it as an ObjectId helps to prevent errors, because only valid IDs can be stored in this attribute.

Answer (score -1):

With mongoose schema definition you don't need to use 'mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID' you can simply pass :

```js
{
  ...
  entity: {
     type: 'ObjectId',
     ref: 'entity'
  }
  ...
}
```

As defined [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_objectid.htm) ObjectId is the default generated _id unique value of document storing timestamp and counter.

for a simple answer to 'when should I use object id ?' : when it refers to another document that use ObjectId

Comment: Why do you think it would be a good idea to pass a string ('ObjectId') as a value for `type`?

Comment: As defined [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html#objectids-and-other-mongoose-types) in documentation you can use 'ObjectId'. Mongoose SchemaType has internal cast method to convert type value pass as string

Comment: You are right about that. Nevertheless my question was more in the direction of: Why would you do that? What is the benefit of passing it as a string?

Comment: Less is more ^^

Comment: Yes, but this will not show an error in your editor if you have a typo. Additionally let's say sometimes in the future the type changes on mongoose side. You will only know during runtime that an error occurs, right?

Comment: Yes you are right +1